# converting the observable of object obtain from rxjs "from" operator to observable of array

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im facing this error while iterating through the Observable. I know it is considering return value of getNumbers method as Object instead of Array.
But, i don't want process the data and create array and then pass it to view.

I want it to be Observable of number array and use this array with ngFor and async to display each element. please let me know how to achieve this.

Here is the code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor() {}

  getNumbers(): Observable<number> {
    return from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  number$;
  constructor(api:ApiService)
  {
    this.number$=api.getNumbers();
  }
}
```

Here is View logic

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let num of this.number$|async">
        {{num}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is the source code reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaj6a4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
  getNumbers(): Observable<number> {
    return from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }
```

the resulting observable emits immediately five values, 1 to 5. If you want to render `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then you need one, `Observable<number[]>`, and two, `of` instead of `from`.

```
  getNumbers(): Observable<number[]> {
    return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }
```

Comment: if from emits immediately then behavior of this code is opposite to what you are saying check this out from([4, 5, 6]).subscribe(x => console.log(x)); && of([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(x => console.log(x));. i'm bit confused. please clear the doubt.

Comment: Immediately as in "there is no time delay between one emission and another". `console.log` will print them all out, but if you try to render them in a HTML template, you'll see only the last one, because 4 will be instantly replaced by 5, and 5 will be instantly replaced by 6.

Comment: No, from is printing all in one short in console and of prints one item at a time which is opposite of what is happening in html template . you check my code in Stackblitz , i have updated.

Comment: Yes, and it works exactly as I said: `from` fires immediately five times, the last value is 5 and it's the only value visible. Put them both in the template without any processing and see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqyf58

Answer (score 0):

Change the `number` to `Array<number>` to make it return an array and change `from` to `of`:

```
getNumbers(): Observable<Array<number>> {
    return of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}
```

Then you can indeed use the `| async` pipe in the template, then you won't need a manual subscription.

Comment: i get Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.  error if i change the return value to Array<number>.

Comment: You also need `of`, not `from`, see my answer.